# dynamically adding multiple classes to wordpress body_class()

Tags: wordpress, class, taxonomy, slug

I'm trying to figure out how to add add terms for pages to my body class automatically. I'm very close with some code I've been piecing together. Right now this works, but only returns one term. How can I get it to return an array of terms each as a class that get's added to the body tag? Here's what I've got so far. fyi "topbar" is my taxonomy name.

```
<?php $class='';
  if(is_page()) {
  $terms = get_terms("topbar");
  $class .= $terms[0]->slug;
}?>
<body id="top" <?php if (function_exists('body_class')) body_class($class ); ?>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if(is_page()) {
    global $post;
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, "topbar", array("fields" => "names"));
    $class = ($terms) ? implode(" ", $terms) : '';
}
?>

<body id="top" <?php if (function_exists('body_class')) body_class($class ); ?>>
```

Cheers ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help vzwick. What you've given me is very close. It currently adds all terms to the body class. I'm looking for it to only add the terms that are checked. So if multiple terms are available but you only select one or two, it will only add those classes to the body tag. Any ideas?

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly, should work the way you want now.

Comment: Seems to no longer add any classes. Is there something I need to change to my own values? Maybe the "fields" and "names". What do those represent? Sorry if I'm being thick headed, I'm just trying to learn as we go here.

Comment: Hum. I don't have a WP instance at hand to test here ... can you do a `var_dump($terms)` right after `$terms = ...` and tell me what the output is? **Edit:** Also, note the edit to my answer.